# How to do `@class` in JOLT

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am using the Java JOLT JSON transformation library and want to know how to spit out an element with @class as the key.  Since '@' is a wildcard it is trying to interpret the symbol instead of outputting it as a string.

I need to specify the java class in order for jackson to map properly.

I want to do something like:

```
"locations": {
                "*": {
                    "#location": "tempLocations[&1].riskItemType",
                    "#com.object.beans.element.Location": "tempLocations[&1].@class",`
```

So it will spit out something like:

```
{"@class": "com.object.beans.element.location"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [json-ld-escaping](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#json-ld-escaping) online example:

> Note in order to escape Shiftr special chars, you have to use two
>   backslashes

Example:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // In this example, we want to change some of the LHS keys in this Json document.
      // To accomplish this we escape the leading '@' chars both as spec matches (left hand side)
      //  and as output paths (right hand side).
      //
      // Note in order to escape Shiftr special chars, you have to use two backslashes,
      //  because Java.
      // Also, all other Shiftr special chars should be escapable: . @ $ & \ [  ]
      "\\@context": {
        "name": "&1.Name",
        "ingredient": "&1.Inputs",
        "yield": "\\@context.Makes",
        // pass the rest thru
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "name": "Name",
      "ingredient": "Inputs",
      "yield": "Makes",
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```